# CVE-2019-11479 convert iptables command to ufw format

Tags: security, iptables, ufw

I'm trying to apply the iptables workaround for the following [CVE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SACKPanic). The iptables command provided

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcpmss --mss 1:500 -j DROP`

works but we are unfortunately using `ufw`, is there a way to explicitly convert the iptables command to a functioning ufw command or a way to provide one off iptable rules to ufw so that it is persisted through system reboots?

Comment: Looks like this is what i'm looking for https://serverfault.com/questions/198398/ubuntu-how-to-add-an-iptables-rule-that-ufw-cant-create

Answer (score 0):

The link in my comment is correct, I was able to add the raw iptables rule to the `/etc/ufw/after.rules` file like so:

```
# CVE-2019-11479
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcpmss --mss 1:500 -j DROP
```

followed by a reload `sudo ufw reload` my iptables shows the correct rule in it's list

```
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcpmss match 1:500
```